# Merging query params with @ngrx/router-store

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm using @ngrx/router-store in my Angular 2+ application and trying to encode some objects in the query params of the url. Specifically, every time I encode an object in the query params, I want to merge it with the query params that are already there. To do this, I've written the following side effect for the router store, as per [the documentation](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/router-store/api.md#effects):

```js
@Injectable()
export class RouterEffects {
  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  navigate$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(RouterActions.GO),
    map((action: RouterActions.Go) => action.payload),
    tap(({ path, query: queryParams, extras}) => {
      this.router.navigate(path, { queryParams,  queryParamsHandling: "merge", ...extras }))
    })
}
```

Then to add new query params I can just dispatch them to the router-store:

```
store.dispatch(new RouterActions.Go({[], objectToEncode}));
```

This works fine unless multiple objects are dispatched in quick succession, for example, when the application is first loaded. In this case, the side effect will begin the next navigation before the previous has completed, meaning the query params of each subsequent navigation will overwrite that of the previous navigation, so only the last object will be encoded in the final url.

**Is there a way to prevent the side effect from processing the next GO action until the previous navigation has completed?** I tried zipping the action with the query params from the store, but this fails when the object being encoded is already in the url, preventing the store from emitting.

Comment: Not exactly clear on the problem. So you have `?first=1` and then `?second=2` and you want the result to be `?first=1&second=2`. Is that right? If so then maybe it would make sense to use the `scan` operator to aggregate the query param state?

Comment: Yep, and you nailed it with the scan operator. The accumulating an object example from the [Learn RxJS GitBook](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @bygrace, the scan operator does the trick. Here's the original code modified to use the scan operator:

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class RouterEffects {
  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  navigate$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(RouterActions.GO),
    map((action: RouterActions.Go) => action.payload),
    scan((currentRoute, {path, query: queryParams, extras}) => {
      const nextQueryParams = Object.assign({}, currentRoute.query, queryParams);
      return {path, query: nextQueryParams, extras};
    }, {path: [], query: {}, extras: {}}),
    tap(({ path, query: queryParams, extras}) => {
      this.router.navigate(path, { queryParams,  queryParamsHandling: "merge", ...extras }))
    })
}
```